# How to handle two Segmented Controllers in one View Controller in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app I want to Handle Two Segmented Controllers in one view Controller.
Upto now I created Like this,

1. Created two `IBAction` for Segmented Controllers.
2. segment1 = 0 and segment = 1 working fine.
3. segment2 = 0 not working.
4. segment2 = 1 Working fine.

my problem is when the user click on segment2 = 0 going to another view.

Here is my Some of code.

```
-(IBAction)segment1:(id)sender
{
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
NSInteger selectedSegment1 = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

if (selectedSegment1 == 0)
{
    view2.hidden = YES;
    view1.hidden = NO;
}
else if (selectedSegment1 == 1)
{
    view2.hidden = NO;
}
}
-(IBAction)segment2:(id)sender
{
UISegmentedControl *segmentSelected2 = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
NSUInteger selectedSegment2 = segmentSelected2.selectedSegmentIndex;
{
    if (selectedSegment2 == 0)
    {
        UIStoryboard *recent = self.storyboard;
        ViewController2 *recentVC = [recent instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
        [self presentViewController:recentVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (selectedSegment2 == 1)
    {
        UIStoryboard *story = self.storyboard;
        ViewController3 *VC = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];
        [self presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: put the break point once and check once the index is called or not

Comment: @anbu.Karthik.segment2 = 0 is not calling?

Comment: segment1= 0 and segment2 = 0 at a time not working in one ViewController.

Comment: you were called the segemnnt in another view controller

Comment: confusion , can you show some additional information related to thsi

Comment: When i click on recent jobs it is not working.but category working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing seems wrong here. The only thing I could see is you are trying to click on RecentJobs when it is already selected.

Try to add this line of code in your view did load `<segmentControlOutletObject>.selectedSegmentIndex = -1` and try clicking on it now.

or

Select the segmented control in your story board (Attributes inspector) and make sure you have the settings shown in the image below for the control

[image]